# Bootstrap table searching is not working (if we have & in between the words)

Tags: bootstrap-table

I am new to bootstrap and working in bootstrap table. I need a data Table having searching functionality using bootstrap-table.
i have implemented the same but when I am trying to search data having '&' in between. It's not displaying any data (search functionality is not working).

Please find my code in fiddler :  //jsfiddle.net/Amit94_Kumar/c5vy46jz/2/ (please add https: before fiddler link)
Example : in above code if we try to search for 'product & N' it show no data

Comment: Can you share J's fiddle here?

Comment: HI Ali please find fiddler link https://jsfiddle.net/Amit94_Kumar/c5vy46jz/3/

Comment: Hi, try using this https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4 I'm unsure which bootstrap datatable you are using in your fidle

Comment: Hi Ali, the above is also not working with '& ' in between the words
I am using https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.10.1/bootstrap-table.js (Bootstrap table)

Comment: Then in this case you should built your own search checkout this https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()

Comment: oh okay will try that Thanks @AliHussnain for your time